# More than one if BASH

Tags: linux, bash

How I can create more then one "if" function in bash ?? for example I want to do something like this :

```
if [ "$answer" == "0" ]; then 0
if [ "$answer" == "1" ]; then 1
if [ "$answer" == "2" ]; then 2
else echo "error"
fi
```

Thanks

Comment: Well, you could begin by using google :D

Comment: `elif` might be something that you want.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use the same test (`"$answer" ==`) than it would be better to use `case`:

```
case "$answer" in
  0) echo "0" ;;
  1) echo "1" ;;
  2) echo "2" ;;
  3|4) echo "3 or 4" ;;
  *) echo "error" ;;
esac
```

You can find many valuable things about Bash scripting here:

1. [Advanced Bash Scripting HOWTO](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/)
2. [Bash pitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls)
3. don't forget about `man bash`

Comment: Skip the Advanced Bash Scripting guide. It contains much bad advice.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `elif`

```
if [ "$answer" == "0" ]; then echo "0"
elif [ "$answer" == "1" ]; then echo "1"
elif [ "$answer" == "2" ]; then echo "2"
else echo "error"
fi
```

Comment: `[ ... == ... ]` is not standards-compliant, use `[ ... = ... ]` (or `[[ ... == ... ]]` for shells that support it, but don't mix).

Comment: And `-eq` if you want them to be treated as integers, i.e. if you want `01` to equal `1`